# Install Zend Server CE On Centos 6.5

Tags: php, zend-server-ce

I am installing **Zend-Server CE** on **Centos 6.5**. I am referring to  this tutorial [Installing Zend Server with Apache](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/rpm_installing_zend_server.htm) with manually setup process. When i run the command `yum install zend-server-ce-php-5.3` then all is going well with downloading but I see some error at the end of this command. Here's a screen shot of the error 
http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=515f1e4

Comment: what error ? please add in your question

Comment: i attached the screen shot. please see the screen shot